# Return NSArray or NSDictionary from a function after parsing a JSON in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have the following function in a Playground that parses a JSON file from an URL and converts it to either a Dictionary or an Array depending on the JSON format and prints out the data. This part works fine but I am not sure how I can return the parsed data so that I can use it outside the function.

Any help is appreciated, here is the swift code I have on the playground...

```
import UIKit

var dataUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/feed/movies.json")!

func getData(NSURL) {
    var dataFile = NSData(contentsOfURL: dataUrl)
    var data:AnyObject?

    let dataObject : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataFile!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

    if let dataDictionaryObject = dataObject as? NSDictionary {
        if let data = dataDictionaryObject as Dictionary? {
           println(data)
        }
    }else if let dataArrayObject = dataObject as? NSArray {
        if let data = dataArrayObject as Array? {
            println(data)
        }
    }
}

getData(dataUrl)
```

Comment: Just return the array or dictionary from your method.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to do so. I've tried to use `return data` and setting the method to return AnyObject but when I try to print the data variable outside the function it says it is undefined.

Comment: If you do not k now if the received JSON is a dictionary or array how are you going to access its contents? You really need to know the format of the JSON object.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example,**replace the URL with your url**.

Just return json data,ecause your method can return different type.So return `AnyObject?`,Then outside the function convert it

```
import UIKit


var dataUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json")!

func getData(NSURL) ->AnyObject?{
    var dataFile = NSData(contentsOfURL: dataUrl)
    var data:AnyObject?

    let dataObject : AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataFile!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

    return dataObject
}
let jsonData: AnyObject? = getData(dataUrl)

if let dataDictionaryObject = jsonData as? NSDictionary {
    if let data = dataDictionaryObject as Dictionary? {
        println(data)
    }
}else if let dataArrayObject = jsonData as? NSArray {
    if let data = dataArrayObject as Array? {
        println(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple solution to a problem I was making too complicated. Thank you for this answer <3

Answer (score 2):

> Return dictionary or array

This sounds like an enum. So let's declare one and use it

```
enum JSONData {
    case Array([AnyObject])
    case Dictionary([String: AnyObject])
}
```

then your method signature looks like this

```
func getData(url: NSURL) -> JSONData
```

And then when you use it:

```
switch getData() {
case let .Array(data): // use it
case let .Dictionary(data): // use it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func getData(url:NSURL, handler: ((object:AnyObject?) -> Void)) {
    var dataFile = NSData(contentsOfURL: dataUrl)
    var data:AnyObject?

    let dataObject : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataFile!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

    if let dataDictionaryObject = dataObject as? NSDictionary {
        if let data = dataDictionaryObject as Dictionary? {
            handler(object: data)
        }
    }else if let dataArrayObject = dataObject as? NSArray {
        if let data = dataArrayObject as Array? {
            handler(object: data)

        }
    }
}
getData(dataUrl, { (object) -> Void in
    println(object);
});
```

//it is better to use Generic if possible.